# How can I get TFS 2017 to copy only the files in my Release folder to a UNC, and not the \drop\Project\bin\Release folder structure?

Tags: c#, tfs, build

Right now I have a build definition setup in TFS 2017 that uses the Publish Artifact:drop build step.

In that build step I have **$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)** as the 'Path to Publish' and **\\server\share\folder** as the Path.

This works, but I get **\\server\share\folder\drop\AppName\bin\Release** with my files inside of the Release folder.

How can I tell TFS to just output the files right into **\\server\share\folder**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than modifying your **Publish Artifact** step you want to arrange the files in your `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` in the way you want them published to your drop folder.

Given you likely have a **Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)** step, in TFS 2017 (Update 1) you can check *Flatten Folders* under *Advanced* and this will drop the file contents into the root of your artifact staging directory.

I don't believe there is a way to get around having the artifact name ("drop" in your case) forming part of the path, but with *Flatten Folders* all files should be dropped in the root of `\\server\share\folder\drop`

**Edit**

An alternative is to specify something like the below in the copy files step. Provide the relative path to your bin\release directory, then use the minimatch `**` pattern in the contents field to copy everything in that directory

[image]

Comment: I don't see an option to Flatten Folders. Maybe I am not on Update 1 yet.

Comment: Added and alternative approach